# Mathematica keeps crashing my machine -- is there a way to prevent Mma from eating up so much system resources so this doesn't happen?

Tags: crash

Fairly often Mathematica crashes on me. I'm pretty sure I'm not doing anything too radical or unusual, but I'll try to run some program and it'll be taking too long to evaluate, so maybe I'll hit alt+. to try and kill evaluation, the window will go grey and say Not Responding. Sometimes I'll still have control my mouse cursor by this point, but nothing responds to clicks (even other applications). Usually eventually it'll stop letting me move the mouse, at which point I have to manually restart my machine. Every time it causes me to lose work and it's very frustrating.

I'm using Windows 8 on a relatively new machine. I run Mathematica 10.0.2.0. I'm not usually doing anything too resource intensive when this happens (maybe have a browser and pdf open, but nothing crazy).

I don't know exactly what bit of code caused this because I just called a function that calls many other functions. I could copy and paste the mass of it but that's not really what I'm interested in here.

My question is, is there some way to throttle Mathematica's CPU usage or something, so that when it tries doing whatever the hell causes it to completely freeze up?

I love MMa but it's very frustrating and it's getting to the point where I save practically every 5 seconds because I just expect it to crash, and that's unacceptable.

Comment: see [TimeConstrained](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeConstrained.html) and [MemoryConstrained](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemoryConstrained.html) and adding `$HistoryLength = 0;` at the top helps also. Other than that, maybe your PC has virus if it keeps crashing like this? I recommend ESET virus protection for PC's. I've been using it for years.

Comment: You should contact `support@wolfram.com` for assistance. If you could send them a crash dump that would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of code that causes this crash?  Your question seems so generic that I doubt much help can be provided.  Perhaps the instability in your system is not Mathematica, but something else.

Comment: This happens a lot when your physical memory runs out and mathematica starts working in virtual memory, resulting in a paralyzing mess of disk swaps. For a discussion see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405304/memory-use-of-apply-vs-map-virtual-memory-use-and-lock-ups).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, your thread is essentially exactly what I'm asking here, but asked much more intelligently.